# Is CloudSolrClient thread safe?

Tags: java, solrj

I am trying to use CloudSolrClient instance in a multithread environment. 
Is CloudSolrClient class thread-safe ? or should it be managed as database connection pool?

Any advise will be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, CloudSolrClient is thread safe and you can share a configured singleton between all your threads.

There are just few [precautions](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7127):

> `CloudSolrClient` isn't thread-safe if you're making requests to
>   multiple collections, because `defaultCollection` is mutable. This can
>   be a pain if you're trying to index into multiple collections from a
>   single queue of documents.

But you can have multiple `CloudSolrClient` instances, one configured for each collection.